# Ace editor's output is truncated and it scrolls up even if there is empty space at the bottom

Tags: ace-editor

I am observing a strange behaviour (though to be honest, I don’t think I tested for this scenario).

I have set the height of ace editor to 500px. The text I have entered is around 60 lines. I see a scroll bar but the text occupies only around 70-80% of the editor. The space below is blank even though there is more text. See the picture below:

[image]

When I type something, though the cursor is at the bottom of the editor, the character gets typed at a higher location

[image]

I suppose there is a mismatch between the height of the ace-editor and the content within the editor. How could I align them?

### Update

I notice that the `top` property of the `textarea` within the editor is changing as I scroll. I am not sure if this should happen as the `textarea` should stay fixed within the `ace-editor` element.

```
<textarea class="ace_text-input" wrap="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" readonly="" style="border: 1px solid black; opacity: 0; font-size: 1px; height: 1px; width: 1px; **top: 458px;** left: 150px;"></textarea>
```

The `top` is initially `458px` and as I scroll, it changes to `98px` and even less if I keep scrolling. I am just sharing my observations here, I do not know how relevant they are.

Answer (score 0):

When the size of the editor is changed by javascript after creating it, you need to call `editor.resize()` for editor to update its size.

Comment: but I am not changing the size of the editor.

Comment: BTW, I found your answer about font types here. I have set the font to `Courier New` just to be sure that I am using a `monospaced` font but the problem still persists - `this.editor.setOptions({
      readOnly: this.readonlyFormStatus,
      fontFamily: "Courier New",
      fontSize: "14pt"
    });` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183031/ace-editor-cursor-behaves-incorrectly

Comment: I have added more details in this question - could you please take a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65603263/the-characters-are-not-getting-typed-where-the-cursor-is/65604858?noredirect=1#comment115992278_65604858