# The characters are not getting typed where the cursor is

Tags: ace-editor

In my Ace editor, just after the scroll bars appear, the character are getting typed but not where the cursor is. See the picture below. What has gone wrong? The code seem to work OK in my dev environment.

[image]

I notice that the font for my dev environment is bigger than the font of my prod environment.

Dev env:

[image]

Prod env:

[image]

I don't understand that why there is a difference and if this is the cause of the issue.

After setting the `fonts` explicitly to `courier new`, the editor options are

```
editor options are   {selectionStyle: "line", highlightActiveLine: true, highlightSelectedWord: true, readOnly: false, copyWithEmptySelection: false, …}animatedScroll: falseautoScrollEditorIntoView: undefinedbehavioursEnabled: truecopyWithEmptySelection: falsecursorStyle: "ace"displayIndentGuides: truedragDelay: 0dragEnabled: trueenableBlockSelect: trueenableMultiselect: truefadeFoldWidgets: falsefirstLineNumber: 1fixedWidthGutter: undefinedfocusTimeout: 0foldStyle: "markbegin"fontFamily: "Courier New"fontSize: "14pt"hScrollBarAlwaysVisible: falsehasCssTransforms: undefinedhighlightActiveLine: truehighlightGutterLine: truehighlightSelectedWord: trueindentedSoftWrap: truekeyboardHandler: undefinedmaxLines: undefinedmaxPixelHeight: 0mergeUndoDeltas: trueminLines: undefinedmode: "ace/mode/html"navigateWithinSoftTabs: falsenewLineMode: "auto"overwrite: falseplaceholder: undefinedprintMargin: 80printMarginColumn: 80readOnly: falserelativeLineNumbers: undefinedscrollPastEnd: 0scrollSpeed: 2selectionStyle: "line"showFoldWidgets: trueshowGutter: trueshowInvisibles: falseshowLineNumbers: trueshowPrintMargin: truetabSize: 4theme: "ace/theme/eclipse"tooltipFollowsMouse: trueuseSoftTabs: trueuseTextareaForIME: trueuseWorker: truevScrollBarAlwaysVisible: falsewrap: "off"wrapBehavioursEnabled: true__proto__: Object
```

### Update

It seems each line in the editor gets a class `ace_gutter-cell`. This class is not the same the `dev` and `prod` environment. `position:absolute` is missing in `prod`. See the images below. Am I picking differing builds of `ace`?

Dev:

[image]

Prod:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use a font that isn't monospaced; you have to use monospaced fonts with Ace.

Comment: I added this but the problem persists `this.editor.setOptions({       readOnly: this.readonlyFormStatus,       fontFamily: "Courier New",       fontSize: "14pt"     });`. I suppose `Courier New` is monospaced font.

Comment: I notice that if when there is no text then the line no. 1 appears in the gutter. Say I enter `a` in line no. 1 and press enter then the line no. in gutter changes to 2. Now I enter `b` in line 2 and press enter. The new line no. is 3. Now if I use up arrow to go to line 1 then line no. of 2 changes from 2 to 3 when I reach 1. If I now move down one stop to go to line 2 then the line no. of 2 correctly changes back from 3 to 2! This for some reason happens only in production release.

Comment: var options = editor.getOptions() will get you all of your settings. It might give  you some clues

Comment: tried it. The options show that the font is `Courier New`. Also, the options are the same in both dev and test environments but strangely the editor is working quite differently. I have updated the question with output of `getOptions`

Comment: Maybe there is some css in the page changing editor styles. Is there a way for you to share the page with error for me to debug, or to create a demo page?

Comment: Did you mess with the theme? The css is set by the theme mostly. Try another theme.